# json_encode string php to javascript but when use it in javascript got null

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, string

script

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var myvar = <?= json_encode($str); ?>;
alert(myvar);
</script>
```

php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?
$str = "ABCD";
echo "ENCODING: " . mb_detect_encoding($str) . "\n";
?>
```

im not good at english sorry.

`$str = "ABCD"`

i want to send string from php to javascript

```
var myvar = <?= json_encode($str); ?>;
```

i use json_encode but when i alert no massage display in alert-box(box happen but no massage there maybe null value)

```
alert(myvar);
```

i dont know what happen please help me
PS.alert for test string i want to use that string in javascript code

Comment: Try `var myvar = '<?= json_encode($str); ?>';`

Comment: are we to assume your php code is in the same file and above your javascript code?

Comment: @dfsq: No, if given a string, `json_encode` puts quotes around it.

Comment: Are the first two snippets from the same or separate files? If separate, is the "php" snippet included before the "script" snippet?

Comment: No, I was wrong, quotes are not needed as json_encode already take care of it.

Comment: thank you my php  under  javascript that make my lose 2hr. for fix it T___T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code try to fix those as below :

- Put the second `<script>` tag after PHP blocks.
- Replace `<? ?>` blocks with `<?php ?>` or `<?= ?>`

Like so :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?=
 $str = "ABCD";
 echo "ENCODING: " . mb_detect_encoding($str) . "\n";
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
 var myvar = <?= json_encode($str); ?>;
 alert(myvar);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you my php  under  javascript that make my lose 2hr. for fix it T___T

Answer (score 0):

- Here are 2 flaws in your code

  - syntex to use php is `<?php $str = "ABCD"; ?>` not `<?$str = "ABCD"?>`
  - echo **"ENCODING: " . mb_detect_encoding($str) . "\n";**  is giving error , so it will not run

PHP code :-

```
<?php 
   $str = "ABCD";
   $message = json_encode($str);
?>
```

Javacript code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var json = <?= json_decode($message); ?>;
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj);
</script>
```